# Is there a way to fetch the author's name of a Sharepoint file in Python?

Tags: python, sharepoint, shareplum

I want to get the author's name (Created By/Modified By) of several files contained in a Sharepoint folder in Python.
I have used the Shareplum library to connect to the site and was able to retrieve some details (for ex- Time Modified/ Time Created) about the files but not the name of the author who has added the file. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please take a while and read [ask] with [mre]. Good luck 

Comment: Can you show us the current code you are using to fetch file details (Time Modified/ Time Created)? You can fetch Created By using "Author" and Modified By using "Editor" - these are internal names of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the internal name of columns in API calls to get the column values from SharePoint list.

Below are internal names for created by and modified by columns:

- Created By: **Author**
- Modified By: **Editor**

Use these column names in your API call along with "Created" and "Modified (which fetches dates) to get the Created By and Modified By values on files.